# ControlSetText is not working in AutoIt Robotframework

Tags: autoit, robotframework

1. I am writing scripts for running the Microsoft Word EXE file
2. Using ControlSetText I am trying to send text, for example, *Hello world*. But it is not getting displayed in Microsoft Word.
3. But for this option sending a keyword is working, but I need a solution for ControlSetText. How can I do it?

#### Sample

```
*** Settings ***

    Documentation    Suite description
    Library     AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***

    ${Word}     C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\WinWord.exe
    ${keys}     Test keyword

*** Test Cases ***

   Microsoft word

        Run     ${Word}
         WinWaitActive    Document1 - Microsoft Word      ${EMPTY}        2
         ControlSetText     Document1 - Microsoft Word      ${EMPTY}        [ClassnameNN :NetUIHWND2]       ${keys}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a word.au3 UDF. Try to use it. Shouldn't be a problem to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks..But I cannot use word.au3 in the autoit Robot framework.Need some other option for controlsettext and ControlGetText. we have Controlsend for sending the value but for retrieving that values ControlGetText is not working. Let me know for any other keyword.